# Claims output empty until multiple login refresh

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I've setup the 'TestWebApp sample on IIS 10, federated with Azure AD.
When logging in the authN completes successfully but the displayed ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims list is empty.
Clicking the 'Login button ~3/4 times does eventually populate the list.

I can see a valid assertion returned from the IDP (AAD), including all issued claims.

Anyone seen this?

Other than that a great package, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds strange, I have not experienced that problem.

Do you see any errors in the browser?

Comment: No errors whatsoever. Thought to ask before rolling up my sleeves.

Comment: I hope you find the problem and please do share your findings.